# Удаление записи через телеграм бот

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, telegram-bot

При удалении записи через тг-бот, удаляются все данные, но мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Удалить" удалялась та запись которая выводилось пользователю, если кто нибудь сталкивался прошу помочь!!!

ниже пример кода:

```
bot.on('callback_query', query => {
    client.query(`select * from person_list`, (err,res) => {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      let jsonString = JSON.stringify(res.rows);
      let jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
      let arr = [];
      for(let i in jsonObj){
          arr.push(jsonObj[i]);
      }
        if (query.data === 'delete'){
            client.query(`delete from person_list where id=${arr[i].id}`, (err,res) => {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                bot.answerCallbackQuery(query.from.id, text=`Пользователь с ID: ${arr[i].id} успешно удален`);
            })
        }
        if(query.data === 'update') {
            bot.sendMessage(query.from.id, "Изменение данных...", opts);
        } else if (query.data === 'person_fio'){
          client.query('INSERT INTO person_list(person_fio) values($1) RETURNING *');
        } else if(query.data === 'person_position'){
          client.query('INSERT INTO person_list(person_position) values($1) RETURNING *')
        } else if(query.data === 'address_id'){
          client.query('INSERT INTO person_list(person_address_id) values($1) RETURNING *')
        } else if(query.data === 'department'){
          client.query('INSERT INTO person_list(department) values($1) RETURNING *')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. Если хотите добавить деталей - отредактийте уже существующий